# C# vs (compiled) PHP performance for computational code?

Tags: c#, php, performance

We're working on a computational engine and currently it's all C# based. The engine does some heavy duty math computations based off input from the front end web pages. Both the front-end and the back-end needs to run in the cloud.

Now, are there any publicly available benchmarks comparing C# to (JIT compiled like Zend) PHP performance for **computational performance**? I'm **NOT** referring to front-end/dynamic webpage performance - there are several published results on that topic. My main concern is back end computations (without going down the ASM/C++ binary route).

Somehow I suspect PHP wasn't designed for that, but the moment some engineers hear 'online computational engine' they start wondering why I'm not using PHP. So I though I'd ask this to the wider community.

PS: Please don't say "I love (PHP .. or C#) therefore ...". This isn't a call for "preferences". Lets keep this scientific for the specific goal of computational performance.

Comment: Easy enough to try some benchmarks. Extract the core of your engine from C#, write it up in PHP. Run both through a loop a few million times, and see which one's faster. You'll probably find that both compute at about the same rate, but PHP will have a slightly higher overhead to do the various typecasts/conversions it does internally.

Comment: C# is much faster than PHP, even compiled PHP, because of static typing. (unless you fill your C# code with `dynamic` and in that case its pretty much the same)

Comment: My idea is that your choice of Cloud provider has a lot more influence than the choice of language....

Answer (score 3):

Why would you trust anything but your own benchmark?  Implement a simple but lengthy computation in each, compile, run and time.  You may have to run it a few times to get a sample large enough to time accurately.  Try not to make your code repeat itself or one of the compilers (probably C#) will optimize stuff out and you will get skewed results.

This isn't that much work.

Comment: I was looking to see if someone had already done this. If their results looked "interesting", we'd kick off deeper investigation by porting parts from C# => PHP. If nothing pops up, I might do what you suggested.

Comment: It should be pretty simple to do--also setting up and coding in the different environments will give you more data-points to base your decision on than simple performance.